# Error in verification/error in connecting to iCloud

Tags: icloud, error, login

I am trying to turn off find my iPhone on my iCloud so I can restore a backup.

Every time I try to do this, I get a message saying

```
Verification Failed
There was an error connecting to iCloud
```

..after entering my password. And if I go to the very top and try to click on my name it tells me:

```
ACCOUNT DETAILS UNAVAILABLE
If you are signing into iCloud on another device or at iCloud.com you can get a verification code offline.
```

Then it has the option to get a verification code. I have family sharing with my aunt so I don't know if that has anything to do with it or not but I can't do anything.